# Inserir dados via SSH com PHP

Tags: ssh

Gostaria de saber uma forma de enviar arquivos para uma VPS via SSH com o PHP !
Alguém poderia me sugerir uma ajuda, pois estou em um servidor de jogo, o mesmo possui um banco de dados interno.

Ao cadastrar o usuário, mandar o arquivo para a vps via SSH.

Answer (score -1):

Use a função Shell_exec do PHP, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('scp <path/arquivo> <user@servidor>:</path/to/>');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Onde:

```
path/arquivo = Path e nome do arquivo que vc quer enviar
user@servidor = Login do usuário e endereço do servidor q vc quer enviar
/path/to/ = Path no servidor para o qual vc está enviando
```

**Obs.:**
 
Para esse script funcionar sua máquina e o usuario tem que estar autorizados no servidor.